# How to install applications with same package name in android?

Tags: android, package

Is it possible to install two different applications with same package name in my real device or Android Emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way. Think of the package as a unique id, or a primary key in SQL tables.

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is, "no". That's also the long answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, no two applications with the same package name can exist in any device. The package name identifies your application, and is one of the things that Can Never Change:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Naturally, you can have different applications with "sibling" package names, so they share a common root. For instance, you could have one application with the package name com.example.foo and another application with the package name com.example.bar.

Comment: What is the advantage to share common root? Mind to tell?

Comment: So then they don't have the same package name, do they.